# Calculate $P(X_3 =2, X_2 = 1 \mid X_1 = 2)$ for given $P(t)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> For given generator
> $\mathbb{G} = \begin{pmatrix}
> a & 3 \\
> b & -1 
> \end{pmatrix}$ choose $a, b$ so that it is a generator for some Markov Chain $(X_t)_{t \geq0}$. 
> Calculate $P(X_3 =2, X_2 = 1 \mid X_1 = 2)$ afterwards.

---

I managed to calculate the transition matrix $P(t)$ by setting $a=-3$ and $b=1$ and deriving the transition matrix from the generator.

The transition matrix is
$P(t) = \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-4t} + 3 & 1 - e^{-4t} \\
3 - 3e^{-4t} & 3e^{-4t} + 1 
\end{bmatrix}$. Where do I go from there?

Comment: $$
\mathbb P(X_3=2,X_2=1\mid X_1=2) = \mathbb P(X_1=2\mid X_0=1)\cdot\mathbb P(X_1=1\mid X_0=2)
$$

Comment: @Math1000 How do we calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 2 | X_0 = 1)$?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев From the transition matrix...

Comment: @Math1000 where does your equation come from anyway? I appreciate any hints as I don't see it clearly.